# How to file with both a W2 and W2c?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, new-york, form-w-2

My employer sent me an incorrect W2. I then received a W2c. The W2c has empty fields that are filled on the W2.

For example: Box 16 has previously reported and corrected. But Box 17 is blank.

My employer suggested filling with both the W2 and W2c.

However I found Turbo Tax support saying to ignore the W2: https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/3840480-hey-i-got-a-w2-and-a-w2c-do-i-need-to-input-both-the-w2-and-the-w2c-or-just-the-w2c-information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the W2 information, overriding it with the corrected field(s) on the W2c: see [I received a Corrected W-2C. I am filing with the W-2C. However the W-2C is blank for income and has only one field filled. Do I input information from the original W-2?](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/3911242)